# What is the best place to put text constant in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular project, and want to set a text constant

```
article_sample = "<h1> This is a sample article </h1>\
      This is the content
      This is the content
      This is the content
      ...
      This is the content"
```

This article_sample is very long(may more than one page). And in my js file, I should use assign `article_sample` if I get null article from backend:

```
if (article == null) {
    article = article_sample;
}
```

I don't want to put the constant or variable `article_sample` in the same js file, because it will take a large proportion of the file and make it unreadable.

So where is the best place to put this constant(or variable)?

Answer (score 1):

You can put this constant inside your `app.js` or in any other files using the following code

```
angular.module('myApp', []).constant('ARTICLE_SAMPLE', '<h1>This is a sample .....');
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) :

> ## constant(name, object);
>
> Because the constants are fixed, they get
> applied before other provide methods. See [$provide.constant()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the basic constant concept in angular, what I am asking is the way about long string constant, which is not suitable to be together within the same js file